# Could we update Sharepoint Custom list with outlook email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, out-of-the-box

I have a requirement which has to be done using oob or using sharepoint 2013 designer. 
I send an email to a person using OOB WF or Sharepoint 2013 designer when a new item is added to a custom list. The person opens the outlook mail which is send by SharePoint WF. Click on reply and types in Done in the body of the email and click on send button. then an another email should trigger to another user. the 2nd person does the same thing then the workflow should complete.

Is this possible using outofbox Sharepoint 2013 ?? using OOB WF's or Designer WF's not using any code ??

Comment: Instead of making user write "done" in the email, why not include a nice button in the email that opens a specific link in SharePoint and triggers the next step in the workflow (or starts a new one)?

Comment: we want the approver to do everything in the outlook itself. I am looking for "Mark as complete" option in outlook syncing the sharepoint 2013. but while syncing the task list to outlook . it is throwing me an error. "We couldn't start syncing your tasks because we need to get a few things set up first. Click here to get started, and then retry syncing your tasks."